# Gnuplottex and subfigures

Tags: floats, gnuplot, gnuplottex

I am having trouble aligning subfigures while using gnuplottex. The code of the attached figure is as follow:

```
\begin{figure}[hb!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
        \gnuplotloadfile[terminal=pdf,terminaloptions={size 5cm,3.8cm}]{GnuPlot/weibull_pdfk1}
        \caption{Weibull PDFs, $\beta = 1$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.24\textwidth}
        \gnuplotloadfile[terminal=pdf,terminaloptions={size 5cm,3.8cm}]{GnuPlot/weibull_cdfk1}
        \caption{Weibull CDFs, $\beta = 1$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Channel and functions Weibull distributions}
    \label{fig1:weibull_dist}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried to remove the `\centering` command as well as the parameters of `\begin{figure}`environment but nothing change. In a same way, modifying the factor of `\textwidth` does not change anyhting: the sub-figure (b) is still aligned on the right side of the column. Do you know any trick to make this work properly? I would like those two sub-figures centered, or at least not in the second column. Thanks!

edit: I can of course resize the plot directly to make it correct, but some space is still wasted and the plot became too small.

[image: figure to align]

Comment: It appears the subfigure is set to be narrower than the images, so the excess is sticking out the right sides.  Either make the subfigures larger, the images smaller, or crop off the excess white space.

Comment: You could use \makebox[\linewidth][c]{\gnuplotloadfile...} to center the image within the subfigure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late replay.